# Counting digits of variable in shell

Tags: shell

I have a project for uni and I'm stuck.

Say I have a variable x=100110110

I need to count all the zeros of the variable, how would I go about doing this in regular Shell (not Bash).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
x=100110110
nulls=$(echo "$x" | sed "s/1//g")    # delete 1's
echo "${#nulls}"                     # count character
```

Comment: An explanation of how this particular code works would be more beneficial instead if just saying "try this". Why should the OP "try this"?

Answer (score 0):

Without bash:

```
echo "$x" | tr -cd 0 | wc -c
```

With bash and maybe other shells

```
x0=${x//[!0]}
echo "${#x0}"
```